# Not recognizing TouchPad, USB, Wifi, or Ethernet on 13.04

Tags: networking, usb, dell, touchpad, 13.04

Had 12.10 before and things were fine. I am using a Dell Vostro 3550 laptop. All devices work fine from the Live USB drive. But after I actually do the install onto my drive, my touchpad, usb ports, wifi and ethernet are not working.

I am dual booting with Win7, have tried upgrades, full reinstalls, recreating the linux partitions. Nothing works. Anything I can try?

Comment: I have the same issue. Touchpad, external keyboard, mouse and wireless don't work after reboot but are fine with a live session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer to my own question. It appears that the installation process from the CD/USB is busted. I went back to 12.10 where all drivers worked fine and did an update through update-manager. I am now on 13.04 and all devices seem to be working now.

Answer (score 4):

I seem to have a similar if not the same problem on a Dell Latitude E5510. I did install from a USB flash drive created from the .ISO file using Unetbootin.

When I created an install USB drive using Unetbootin and then proceeded to use it to install Ubuntu 13.04 I encountered the same problem e.g. no mouse, trackpad, etc. It appears that Unetbootin can't handle something in the Ubuntu 13.04 .ISO.

When I recreated the install USB drive using the default "Startup Disk Creator" program and re-installed Ubuntu 13.04, I ended up with a fully functional system.